# Pip issue installing mahotas

Tags: python-3.x, pip, centos8, mahotas

I am new to python. I am trying to install Mahotas package in my CentOS machine.

- Command: `sudo pip3 install mahotas`
- Python version: 3.6.8
- Os: CentOS 8

Error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-e01qget1/mahotas/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-_ao2xjit-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-e01qget1/mahotas/
```

Answer (score 1):

Author of mahotas here. There is too little information to figure out what is wrong.

I recommend you try using conda to install mahotas: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mahotas